# How to convert and save User Control with data in to image?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I want the user ba able to save the custom User Control in to image while the data are from other form.
i can't seems to find a way to convert this with the data in to image.

here is the User Control [image]

this is the method to display the user Control... the Bitmap part is when i try to capture immage of the User Control but it is without data...

```
 void AddIncomingmsd(String Name, String ID, String Date, String Department, String Sched, String Pos, 
        String basic, String Holiday, String overtime, String Leave, String tbasic, String tHoliday, String tovertime, 
        String tLeave, String tincome, String sss, String phic, String pib, String tax, String cash, String deduct, String net, string date, string company)
    {
        var payslip = new PaySlip1();
        pnlcontainer.Controls.Add(payslip);
        payslip.BringToFront();
        payslip.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        payslip.Padding = new Padding(0, 10, 0, 0);

        b = new Bitmap(payslip.Width, payslip.Height);
        payslip.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height));


        payslip.Empname = Name;
        payslip.Empid = ID;
        payslip.payperiod = Date;
        payslip.depart = Department;
        payslip.sched = Sched;
        payslip.position = Pos;

        payslip.nname = Name;
        payslip.iid = ID;
        payslip.payp = Date;
        payslip.date = date;

        payslip.basic = basic;
        payslip.holiday = Holiday;
        payslip.overtime = overtime;
        payslip.leave = Leave;

        payslip.tbasic = tbasic;
        payslip.tholiday = tHoliday;
        payslip.tovertime = tovertime;
        payslip.tleave = tLeave;
        payslip.tincome = tincome;

        payslip.SSS = sss;
        payslip.PHIC = phic;
        payslip.PIB = pib;
        payslip.tax = tax;
        payslip.Cashadv = cash;
        payslip.tDeduct = deduct;

        payslip.net = net;
        payslip.company = company;

    }
```

this is the method to insert data to the User Control...

```
 public void nameidgross()
    {
                string name = Computation.name;
                string ID = Computation.id;
                string payperio = Payroll.payperiod;
                string depart = Computation.depart;
                string sched = Computation.sched;
                string position = Computation.position;
                double rate = Computation.rate;
                double holirate = Computation.holidayrate;
                double overhr = Computation.overhr;
                double leavehr = Computation.leavehr;
                double basic = Math.Round(Computation.basic, 2);
                double holipay = Computation.holidaypay;
                double tover = Computation.totalover;
                double tleave = Computation.totalleave;
                double tgross = Computation.tlgross;
                double cash = Computation.totalcash;
                double tdeduc = Computation.totaldeduct;
                double net = Math.Round(Computation.netpay, 2);
                string company = PayrollForm.company;
  
                    ss = Computation.ss;
                    ph = Computation.php;
                    pg = Computation.pg;

  AddIncomingmsd(name, ID, payperio, depart, sched,
                    position, rate.ToString(), holirate.ToString(),
                    overhr.ToString(), leavehr.ToString(),
                    basic.ToString(), holipay.ToString(), tover.ToString(),
                    tleave.ToString(), tgross.ToString(), ss.ToString(),
                    ph.ToString(), pg.ToString(), Computation.Ttax.ToString(), cash.ToString(),
                    deducted.ToString(), net.ToString(), date, company);
 }
```

and this method is for the button to save image...

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nameidgross();
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "image " + Payroll.payperiod + ".jpg";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
            {
                b.Save(Stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [`Control.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Rectangle)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) Method.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Control.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Rect)` to create the bitmap based on content within the form. Stream operations like this can often throw exceptions, so performing these actions within a try/catch block is best practice. You can then save the bitmap to a file (if needed) like so:

```
try
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        ActiveForm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, targetRectSize);
        bmp.Save(@"c:/directory/filetobecreated.imgextension");
    }
{
catch
{
    <handle exception...>
}
```

See the MSDN documentation for [Control.DrawToBitmap()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for more info.